# Syntax error or Access violation when deleting a constraint

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an ADODB connection to an SQL Server Database. I was trying to delete a automatically generated constraint in one of my table that was made by SQL Server Migration Assistant.

The code to delete constraint looks like:

```
conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD] DROP CONSTRAINT [PROD$[C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\PROD.accdb]].{K2K214-423232-1231-CSD9-ASD}]"
```

The error message that I get is

> Syntax error or Access violation

If I change the constraint name to something random

```
conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD] DROP CONSTRAINT random"
```

I get run-time error:

> 'random' is not a constraint

The error looks like it is caused by this name but I cannot figure out why

```
[PROD$[C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\PROD.accdb]].{K2K214-423232-1231-CSD9-ASD}]
```

I also know that the T-SQL is not wrong because if I run the query in SQL Server Management studio:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD] DROP CONSTRAINT [PROD$[C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\PROD.accdb]].{K2K214-423232-1231-CSD9-ASD}]
```

it executes successfully

Comment: Make sure that user your are using to connect with SQL using ADODB have access rights to delete the constraints

Comment: This constraint name is an excellent example of how not to name things. I think you have an unescaped special character somewhere in the name (my bet is on "$" or "\").

Comment: Did you try wrapping single quotes around the name of the constraint, like this `conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD] DROP CONSTRAINT '[PROD$[C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\PROD.accdb]].{K2K214-423232-1231-CSD9-ASD}]'"`

Comment: Does not work. It says it is not a cosntraint

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works but renaming the constraint and deleting it works for some reason. If someone has an idea please explain why

`conn.Execute "sp_rename '[PROD$[C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\PROD.accdb]].{K2K214-423232-1231-CSD9-ASD}]', 'FK_delete';` "

```
conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_delete"
```